# JSF + Liferay: Cannot send parameters from a bean to another

Tags: jsf, liferay, portlet

I've tried all methods, nothing works, in the destination `@PostConstruct` the parameter is null.

I am sending a redirect from BeanA to a page (backed by BeanB) and trying to extract the parameter from BeanB. The requirement is to not add the parameters to the URL.

I tried all methods:

- `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("userId", userId);`
- `@SessionScoped` bean,
- `ec.getFlash().put("userId", userId);`

Any suggestions?
I am redirecting with:

```
 FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        facesContext.getExternalContext().redirect(url);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The portlet API knows two session scopes: `PORTLET_SCOPE` and `APPLICATION_SCOPE`

The default bridge maps all attributes in the session map to `PORTLET_SCOPE`, that means those attributes are only visible to the portlet.

If you want to write and read session attributes for all portlets, you have to use:

```
PortletSession session = ((PortletSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().
    getExternalContext().getSession(true));

// set
session.setAttribute(attributeName, value, PortletSession.APPLICATION_SCOPE);
// get
Object value = session.getAttribute(attributeName, PortletSession.APPLICATION_SCOPE);
```

In a XHTML you can use `#{httpSessionScope.attributeName}` as well.

Comment: Now I see, that's why I get null al the time.Is this about Inter Portlet Communication? I'll check it out. Thanks

Comment: This is the only thing that worked! So the conclusion is that in Liferay this is the only method to sending data between portlets?

Comment: By the way, your comment in code // or should be something like // get

Comment: This is _not_ Inter Portlet Communication as defined by the Portlet API (that would be using events, you can read more about it in the [Liferay Wiki about Events](http://www.liferay.com/de/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Portlet+to+Portlet+Communication) ), but it is how portlet interacted with each other before IPC was invented with Portlet API 2.0. And it is still a common interaction procedure. - I changed the comments

Answer (score 0):

Append your parameters in String URL as queryString like following:

```
String url = "/your-link" + "?param1=" + paramValue;
FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        facesContext.getExternalContext().redirect(url);
```

Here `"/your-link"` is you page link and `paramValue` is some static / dynamic value of the bean. In the init of second bean you can extract parameters from the `HttpServletRequest` object as following:

```
ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)
    (externalContext.getRequestMap().get("com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortletServletRequest"));
PortletRequest portletRequest = (PortletRequest) request.getAttribute("javax.portlet.request");

HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = null;
String param1 = null;
if(portletRequest != null){
    httpServletRequest = PortalUtil.getOriginalServletRequest(PortalUtil.getHttpServletRequest(portletRequest));
    param1 = httpReq.getParameter("param1");    
}
```

If parameters not found with `request.getParmeter`, try extracting it from `request.getQueryString()`.

Comment: He is talking about a portlet application, where you can't cast the request to `HttpServletRequest`.

Comment: You can extract HttpServletRequest from portletRequest.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't want the parameters to appear in the URL. Thanks

Comment: @parkash You should mention then how the HttpServletRequest is extracted from portletRequest, as this is not obvious from your code snippet

Comment: You've made it worse: why do you retrieve the request twice?

Comment: request contains PortletServletRequest to get portletRequest  from it while httpServletRequest is original request to extract parameters.